# Diferença entre event.key e event.code

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre `event.key` e `event.code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

`event.key` representa o valor da tecla pressionada pelo usuário, levando em consideração o estado das teclas modificadoras, por exemplo: `Shift`, bem como a localidade e o layout do teclado.

`event.code` representa uma tecla física no teclado (em oposição ao caractere gerado ao pressionar a tecla). Em outras palavras, esta propriedade retorna um valor que não é alterado pelo layout do teclado ou pelo estado das teclas modificadoras.

Aqui existe um código com exemplo que exibe os dois valores: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code